# How to speed up execution of for loop in Python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, time-complexity

I have coded a `for` loop, with conditional statement and updates made to a list variable at every iteration, which probably is making the process really slow. Is there a way to speed up this process and accomplish the same results as this code snippet performs?

```
fault_array =[] 
for i in x_range_original:
  for j in range(0,16):
    lower_threshold = min(df_records[:,j+1])
    upper_threshold = max(df_records[:,j+1])

    if((df_log[i,j] < lower_threshold) or (df_log[i,j] > upper_threshold)):
      print("Fault detected at timestep: ",df_records['Time'][i])
      fault_array.append(1)
    else:
      print("Normal operation at timestep: ",df_records['Time'][i])

      fault_array.append(0)
```

Comment: Many things are not clear, e.g `df_log`, `df_records`. pls. edit your question and add more information.

Comment: @Samha' I don't think clarification of variables is needed right? My question is pertaining to the checking of values in a for loop, which takes considerable time. If this could be performed in a way which is faster (say list comprehensions, not sure if it works here), that would be the appropriate solution probably.

Comment: I can't get to understand the actual processing effort taken by the loop-body. Understanding the code absolutely helps. Otherwise, you should decrease your code to a more minimized sample, and eliminate trivialities.

Comment: try to convert x_range_original to an function generator or an iterator to avoid consume of memory https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Comment: You use `df_` as variables here. Are these dataframes from Pandas? If not, can you use numpy or pandas? As you can much more easily express those ideas in Pandas/numpy, and it will be much faster than anything you can write in Python.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I don't think the array will ever contain `1`s. Is that right?

Comment: Don't ask a question if you aren't prepared to provide a [mcve] - that means providing a sample of inputs like `df_log`!  The way you index `df_log[i,j]` suggests it is a `numpy` array.  You can't index a list like that.  Iterating over elements of such array is slow.  Using numpy whole-array methods will be a lot faster.

Comment: Without the prints you possibly could cast this as a list comprehension.  But that won't make a big difference in speed.  Putting the `i` loop inside the `j` one would reduce the number of times you define the thresholds.  The prints also take time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mini code review:

```
fault_array =[] 
for i in x_range_original:
  for j in range(0,16):
    # recomputed on every i; perhaps you wanted j to be an outer loop
    # use vectorized versions of min and max
    lower_threshold = min(df_log[:,j])
    upper_threshold = max(df_log[:,j])

    # this condition is never true:
    # df_log[i,j] cannot be less than min(df_log[:,j])
    # same about upper threshold
    if((df_log[i,j] < lower_threshold) or (df_log[i,j] > upper_threshold)):
      print("Fault detected at timestep: ",df_records['Time'][i])
      fault_array.append(1)
    else:
      # perhaps you need to use a vectorized operation here instead of for loop:
      # fault_array = df.apply(lambda row: ...)
      print("Normal operation at timestep: ",df_records['Time'][i])
      fault_array.append(0)
```

Besides the always negative condition, I imagine you were looking for something like:

```
columns = list(range(16))
# I guess the thresholds logic should be different
upper_thresholds = df[columns].max(axis=0)
lower_thresholds = df[columns].min(axis=0)
# faults is a series of bools
faults = df[columns].apply(lambda row: any(row < lower_thresholds) or any(row > upper_thresholds), axis=1)
normal_timesteps = df_records.loc[faults, 'Time']
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Sorry, I had a typo in the question, the threshold is calculated using min-max for df_records, not df_log (updated the question). Will the same logic hold now as per your answer please? Thanks